# What font is used in this image?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

What font is used in the following image?

[image]

The original image URL is https://www.flickr.com/photos/parisinfourmonths/8581256343/in/set-72157632102589845.

I'm also open to any recommendations of fonts that might play nicely in it.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases.  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 7):

According to [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+1+32H+2+TJ+2+25Q+2+TL+2+26U+2+1EY+3+2CV+3+688+3+2CU+3+N6+3+2W7+3+42X+3+ZA+3+8RG+3+GNN+3+1S7+3+4R3+3+2QNX+3+2QNV+3+CMN+4+6OC+4+2DPC+4+2NH+4+KQ+4+5GX+4+NGM+4+NGN+4+NGO+4+U2+4+G9B+4), it appears to be a variant of [Parisian](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/parisian/), a classic Art Deco font from 1928:

[image: Sample]

Comparing your image to the sample above, it looks like the font in your image has slightly sharper corners than most of the cuts of Parisian I could find, and lacks some of the subtle line thickness variation.  Still, it's obviously a variant of the same font.

For similar or matching fonts, you may want to take a look at [Didone](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didone_%28typography%29) typefaces, which are characterized by high line-width contrast and clean geometric letterforms.  While the "defining" examples of the style, like [Didot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didot_%28typeface%29) and [Bodoni](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodoni), are slab-serif typefaces, there are also sans-serif fonts with a similar style.  A few modern examples I happened across while writing this are the [Grenale](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/insigne/grenale/) family and [Vanitas](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/vanitas/).

**Edit:** I think the specific Parisian variant in your image may be [Upper East Side](http://www.dafont.com/uppereastside.font?text=LA+LUMIERE&psize=l) by David Rakowski:

[image: Sample]